# Dots navigation positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

Right, Heres the jsFiddle.

`<html>`http://jsfiddle.net/u9ddkj74/2/

The dots for the slideshow navigation aren't positioning correctly. See how the position is set to absolute and not relative. This is because when i set it to relative the dots disappear.

And with the position to absolute they wont stay with the slideshow so i cannot center the dots with the slideshow as they wont stay in a position.

Any help would be great. Long story short. Just want the dots to be center with the slideshow and stay there so when the browser window is a different size the dots dont go in a weird position,

Comment: Please post your relevant code within SO aswell, this is to prevent the link breaking in the future, if you post your code here, then if the link does break.. your question will remain valid.

Comment: remove `left: 575px;` from `.banner .dots`? http://jsfiddle.net/u9ddkj74/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should position navigation using:

```
.banner .dots {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 325px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9ddkj74/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.dots {
    left: 50%;
    padding: 0;
}
```